# How to do an espresso test on an Array Adapter within an List View?

Tags: android-studio, android-espresso

My application gets search results and puts this in a list view but I am trying to test what that result it.
[Here is a screenshot of what the search result page looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gTqB.png) My code for the displaying of the items is below, as well as what I've tried to use to test the data.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchItemsActivity.this);
                        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
                        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.listView)).atPosition(1)
            .check(matches(withText("Harry Potter Books - "+"In Stock"+"\n"+"Email: test12345@test.com\n"+"Full hardcover series\n")));
```

The error code I'm getting is

```
androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with text: is "Harry Potter Books - In Stock\nEmail: test12345@test.com\nFull hardcover series\n"' doesn't match the selected view.                                                                                   
 Expected: with text: is "Harry Potter Books - In Stock\nEmail: test12345@test.com\nFull hardcover series\n"
 Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=16908308, res-name=text1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=215, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams@ce20b7f, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=Harry Potter Books - In Stock\nEmail: test12345@gmail.com\nFull hardcover series\n, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Barista library for UI tests, it is the easiest solution and makes everything easier. https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista

With Barista, you can do it like this:

```
assertDisplayedAtPosition(R.id.list, 0, "text");
assertDisplayedAtPosition(R.id.list, 0, R.id.text_field, "text");
assertDisplayedAtPosition(R.id.list, 0, R.string.hello_world);
assertDisplayedAtPosition(R.id.list, 0, R.id.text_field, R.string.hello_world);
assertCustomAssertionAtPosition(R.id.list, 0, customViewAssertion);
```

You can find more info on the Github page, it covers everything you need.